# opencv & c++ with objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv

I need to write a program in C++ using OpenCV library and run it within an Objective-C program that someone gave me.
I don't have any prior knowledge about Objective-C, so is it possible to do this properly and how should I start?
I mean, Can I make my C++ & OpenCV program as it is a stand alone program and then include it in the Objective-C one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So er... what's your actual problem here?

Comment: Is there a special way to write my C++ program to make it possible to be included in the Objective-C one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mixing+c%2B%2B+objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing Objective-C and C++ is fine with Xcode and Apples LLVM compiler. Might be done in a number of ways and modes, so yes you may build your C++ & OpenCV module and then use some  Objective-C wrappers.

Comment: Your question is very broad, the way you do this must be carefully designed, or you might end up with some really messy glue-code and build problems.